# List with apps icon in android

Tags: android, android-layout

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
     PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

     ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>)pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {

            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));


            Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        } 

     lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

    }
```

How can I modify this code in order to add those listed app with their own icon ? what should include in main.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        PInfo pInfo = new PInfo();
        pInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        pInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        pInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(pInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

the above return a array list of PInfo. That is a list of appnams,icons and also package names of all the installed apps.

Comment: lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getInstalledApps()))...It show a list of words...so, do I need create my own layout for this ?

Comment: Yes exactly refer this  http://rkancharla.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/android-dynamic-list-view-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this Helper class

```
class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
    private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
    }
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```